# MongoDB Bson creating in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, what I would like to do is Under property address I would like to save person's name and age, it might be one person per property or more than one, so I am trying with just name first but I am getting error.

Json

```
{
    "property": "This is property address",
    "address1": "address 1",
    "address2": "address 2",
    "city": "city name",
    "people": [
        "Person 1",
        "Person 2",
        "Person 3",
        "Person 4"
    ]
}
```

C# code

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
names.Add("person 1");
names.Add("person 2");
names.Add("person 3");
names.Add("person 4");

var document = new BsonDocument {

    {"property", "10" },
    {"address", "this is address 1" },
    {"city", "city name" },
    {"Family Members", new BsonArray {
        new BsonDocument { {"name", names.ToBsonDocument() } }
        } }
    };
```

but I am getting bellow error

> An Array value cannot be written to the root level of a BSON document.

look forward to you help.

Comment: thank you veeram and do apologise for formating

Comment: if I change my c# code to              var document = new BsonDocument {

                {"property", "10" },
                {"address", "this is address 1" },
                {"city", "city name" },
                {"Family Members", new BsonArray {
                    new BsonDocument { {"name", "Person1" }, { "age", 33} },
                    new BsonDocument { {"name", "Person2" }, { "age", 63} },
                    new BsonDocument { {"name", "Person3" }, { "age", 23} }
                    } }

                }; it works but when I try to use list i get error

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, You con use `BsonArray(IEnumerable<string> strings)` constructor like this:

```
var names = new[]
{
    "Person 1",
    "Person 2",
    "Person 3",
    "Person 4"
};

var document = new BsonDocument
{
    {"property", "10"},
    {"address", "this is address 1"},
    {"city", "city name"},
    {"Family Members", new BsonArray(names)}
};
```

That result is:

```
{ 
    {
        "property" : "10",
        "address" : "this is address 1",
        "city" : "city name",
        "Family Members" : ["Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4"]
    }
}
```